# Invariants of objects in $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathrm{Ab})$ up to chain homotopy

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories, infinity-categories, chain-complexes

$\newcommand\Ab{\mathrm{Ab}}\newcommand\ab{\mathrm{ab}}\DeclareMathOperator\Ch{Ch}\DeclareMathOperator\Kom{Kom}\newcommand\ho{\mathrm{ho}}$Let $\Ab$ be the category of finitely generated abelian groups, $\ab$ be the subcategory with objects being the free ones, and $\Ch(\Ab)$ be the category of chain complexes over $\Ab$.

Finally, define $\Kom(\Ab) := \Ch(\Ab)/\ho$ to be the category whose objects are the same as those of $\Ch(\Ab)$, with morphisms space:

$$\Kom(\Ab)[X,Y] := \Ch(\Ab)[X,Y] \,/\, \{\text{chain-homotopy}\}.$$

**I aim to tell if any two objects $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic in $\Kom(\Ab)$.**

One naïve invariant is the homology $H(-)$. Namely, if $H(X) \not \simeq H(Y)$ then $X \not\simeq Y$ in $\Kom(\Ab)$. However, this invariant is known to be "too weak" by algebraic topologists and algebraic geometers. In the context of algebraic topology, $X$ and $Y$ often are simplicial cochain complexes of some actual topological space $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$. There, one can study extra structures (e.g. cup products, Steenrod operations) on the homology $X$ and $Y$ to have a better chance to tell $X$ and $Y$ apart.

#### Question

Nevertheless, not all $X$ and $Y$ comes from an actual topological space. I wonder if there are invariants (other than homology) for objects in $\Kom(\Ab)$ (or $\Kom(\ab)$ if it is any easier).

#### Remarks

###### The same question for derived category is "trivial".

If classifying isomorphism classes in $\Kom$ turns out to be too hard, one may ask the same question for the derived categories $D(\Ab)$. Thanks to Fernando Muro's hint in the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435414/invariants-of-objects-in-operatornamech-mathrmab-up-to-chain-homotopy#comment1121793_435414), I now know that taking homology is a complete invariant in our case. Essentially, this is because $\Ab$ is a hereditary category, i.e. a category $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathcal{A}}^2(-,-) = 0$ [3, section 1.3]. In abelian and hereditary categories $\mathcal{A}$, each bounded $X \in D(\mathcal{A})$ is isomorphic to $H(X)$ (see [3, Theorem 2.1] for a clear proof; a proof for unbounded $X$ is given in [4], but I found it confusing), and the converse is true [2].

For more general, non-hereditary categories $\mathcal{A}$, I wish to delegate the discussion to [another thread "Invariants of objects in $D(\mathcal{A})$ for non-hereditary category $\mathcal{A}$" on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4587254/invariants-of-objects-in-d-mathcala-for-non-hereditory-category-mathcal).

#### Related

Dror Bar-Natan's proof for that a certain chain complex (over a certain preadditive category) up to chain homotopy is an invariant of a tangle. [1]

#### Reference

[1] [Khovanov's homology for tangles and cobordisms-[Dror Bar-Natan]](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410495)

[2] [Hanno's answer on "If the cohomology of two objects in the derived category are equal, are the objects isomorphic?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1204064/562467)

[3] [Hereditary Categories. Lectures 1 and 2 - Helmut Lenzing](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Ebernhard.keller/ictp2006/lecturenotes/lenzing1.pdf)

[4] Henning Krause’s “Derived categories, resolutions, and Brown representability”

Comment: If you considered the derived category rather than the homotopy category, homology would suffice. The homotopy category is more complicated.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Do you mean if I instead want invariant for objects in $D(Ab)$, then $H(-)$ is a complete invariant? - And yeah, I'm aware that the homotopy category is more complicated. Are there any partial results at least?

Comment: It is not hard to see that every chain complex of free abelian groups splits as a direct sum of $2$-term chain complexes. From this one sees that in your $\operatorname{Kom}(ab)$ two objects are isomorphic iff their homologies are isomorphic.

Comment: The discussion of cup products seems unrelated: even if chain complexes come from spaces, any additional algebraic structure they might inherit from this is lost and doesn't matter anymore once you ask whether they are equivalent purely as objects in $\operatorname{Kom}(Ab)$. It's a bit like responding to the question "are finite sets bijective iff they have the same number of elements" with "for finite groups, we know that they are not characterized by their number of elements, and finite sets sometimes come from finite groups".

Comment: @AchimKrause Thanks! Yes, for $Kom(ab)$ it's enough to look at their homologies (by [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), which works not only for $\mathbb{Z}$ but general PIDs). And for $Kom(Ab)$ in general, it is so hard that it remains open? -- I understand your second comment as follows (please correct me if I'm wrong): Given an isomorphism class $[X]$ in $Kom(Ab)$, there is no (why?) canonical construction of a space $\tilde{X}$ (up to space-level homotopy equivalence), so mentioning cup product does not make sense here.

Comment: It's a bit like asking for a canonical basis on an abelian group (note that the singular chain complex of a space comes with a preferred basis, which gets forgotten when passing into $\operatorname{Kom}(Ab)$)

Comment: Please, do not change standard notation, since this is a source of confusion. $\mathbf{Ab}$ (or $Ab$) is the category of *all* abelian groups. If you want to consider the subcategory of f.g. abelian groups, you can name it $\mathbf{Ab}_{\text{fg}}$ for example. Small letters such as $\mathbf{ab}$ actually often indicate *finite* versions, so again it's a bad idea for this to be the category of free abelian groups. Better write $\mathbf{Ab}_{\text{free}}$ (for example). Also, $K(\mathcal{A})$ is the established notation for the homotopy category of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @Student There's no hope to classify objects in the homotopy category of chain complexes of abelian groups, I believe. I think this would contain the classification of pairs $(A,B)$ where $A$ is an abelian group and $B\subset A$ is a subgroup. This is a **wild** problem of representation theory.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Perhaps we should not be discouraging students from asking reasonable questions here by chastising them too much for not being familiar with our preferred notation, especially when they do such a clear job of establishing their notation for the questions. (And for what it's worth, I've certainly seen "Kom" before.)

Comment: Kom(A) is the notation for the category of complexes in Gelfand-Manin...

Comment: @FernandoMuro If it's hopeless as you said, perhaps the best I can ask for is the invariant for objects in the derived category? However, in your first comment, you seemed to suggest that $X \simeq Y$ in $D(Ab) \Leftrightarrow H(X) \simeq H(Y)$. By definition, I get how $\Rightarrow$ is done, but I don't see how you prove $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: @Student please have a look at Achim Krause’s comment. It’s a pretty standard argument. You’ll find it in many introductory texts on derived categories. Like Henning Krause’s “Derived categories, resolutions, and Brown representability”.

Comment: The most straightforward generalization of homology that applies is the following. If $W$ is an object of $Ab$, then you get functors $Kom \to Ab$ given by 
$X \mapsto Hom_{Kom}(W[n],X).$
When $W = \Bbb Z$, these are the ordinary homology groups of $X$. These are essentially generated by both the ordinary homology functors $H_n$ and by the "$d$-torsion homology" functors $X \mapsto H_n (X_{d\text{-tors}})$, where $X_{d\text{-tors}} \subset X$ is the subcomplex of elements annihilated by a fixed integer $d$.

Comment: @GregFriedman I do not understand why mentioning the standard notation should be a form of discouragement from asking. Changing the notation can be done easily in the current question via an edit or in future questions. Clearly, this doesn't affect if the question is being asked or not. What would you do if someone asks a question which starts "Let $\mathbf{Grp}$ be the category of finite abelian groups" or "Let $\pi := 5$?

Comment: @FernandoMuro Thanks for hinting. I found literature on hereditary categories and how taking homologies in their derived category is a complete invariant (that includes $Ab$). I added this into the post. // For those who are following and got confused by Fernando's comment: Achim only talked about $Kom(ab)$, in which homology is also a complete invariant essentially because of Smith normal form (works for modules any PID). // Martin: I appreciate your suggestion. If there's anyway I can undo and fix all notations in all comments so far, I'm happy to do so.

Comment: @Student Kom(ab) is the same as D(Ab).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I think mentioning possibly better notation is fine. I think telling a poster that their notation is a "bad idea" and focusing exclusively on the notation and not the question (when the poster's notation, at least in my opinion, is reasonably good enough and the question is pretty clear) risks being discouraging. It's possible I was being overly sensitive when I read your comment, but it struck me as being unnecessarily critical. In any case, I'm glad the original poster seems pretty undeterred!